# Depletion region

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In a semiconductor diode. There is a depletion region formed, it is formed when electrons from n type side migrate to p type side, now which electrons transfer? Valence band ones present at the boundary or the conduction band ones?  If the conduction band ones only migrate, then are there enough present on the boundary such that they can create a field at the boundary that they can stop this diffusion process?

By boundary i mean the border of n type and p type material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Electrons in the $n$-type conduction band diffuse across the boundary into the empty conduction band of the $p$-type semiconductor. Once there they recombine with holes in the $p$-type valence band. So the net motion of electrons is from the $n$-type conduction band to the $p$-type valence band. This means that near the boundary there are no electrons in the conduction band and no holes in the valence band i.e. the material becomes insulating.

The transfer of electrons causes the $p$ side to become negatively charged and the $n$ side positively charged. As electrons move, the charge separation creates an electric field that opposes the electron diffusion.